# How to extract numbers from JSON API

Tags: python, json, numbers, extract

I want to extract numbers and calculate the sum of these numbers from JSON API. The format is

```
{
      comments: [
      {
        name: "Matthias"
         count: 97
      },
      {
        name: "Geomer"
        count: 97
      }
      ...
     ]
   }
```

And my code is

```
import json
import urllib

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_204529.json'
print 'Retrieving', url
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

result = json.loads(url)
print result
```

I can get the result of how many characters in this data but cannot continue with the code because it's said JSON object cannot be decoded.

Does anyone know how to finish this code? Much appreciated!

Comment: `json.loads(url)` should be `json.loads(data)`.

Comment: How do I extract numbers from the data? Thanks!

Comment: `result.comments[0].count`, `result.comments[1].count`, etc.

Comment: if you just want the sum `sum(d["count"] for d in result["comments"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you study the built-in Python [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to get a better understanding about what you are dealing with.

`result` is a *dictionary*, `result["comments"]` is a *list of dictionaries* - you can make a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get all the comments counts:

```
>>> import json
>>> import urllib
>>>
>>> url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_204529.json'
>>> uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
>>> result = json.load(uh)
>>>
>>> [comment["count"] for comment in result["comments"]]
[100, 96, 95, 93, 85, 85, 77, 73, 73, 70, 65, 65, 65, 62, 62, 62, 61, 57, 50, 49, 46, 46, 43, 42, 39, 38, 37, 36, 34, 33, 31, 28, 28, 26, 26, 25, 22, 20, 20, 18, 17, 15, 14, 12, 10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 3]
```